# Read png image with cv2.imread form Opencv3 in Python3.7.1 and no pixel at all with black window

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, image-processing, png, opencv3.0

I have two png images, **one** is outputed by python library pillow to png, converted from svg font image, **another** is this one read by and re-saved from windows 10's paint program to png.

Strangely, I use opencv3 cv2.imread function to read these images, **one** is not OK with only black window, **another** is OK.

How to read these pngs both correctly?

CODE:

```
import cv2

image_file_path = r""
image = cv2.imread(image_file_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

if(! os.path.exists(image_file_path)):
    print('NOT EXIST! = ' + image_file_path)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

IMAGES:

OK:
[image]

NOT OK:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first image is in 4-channel RGBA format with a completely  pointless, fully opaque, alpha channel which you can ignore.

The second image is in 2-channel Grey+Alpha format where all the pixels are pure solid black and the shapes are defined only in the alpha channel.

So, basically you want to:

- discard the last channel of the first image, which you can do by using `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`
- discard all except the last channel of the second image, which you can do like this:

  `im = cv2.imread('2.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[:,:,-1]`

---

I obtained the information above by using **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available on macOS and Windows.

The command I used in Terminal is:

```
magick identify -verbose 2.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Image: 2.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1040x1533+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Gray: 1-bit                     <--- Note 1
    Alpha: 8-bit                    <--- Note 1
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 1594320
    Gray:
      min: 0  (0)                   <--- Note 2
      max: 0 (0)                    <--- Note 2
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 4.82164e-05
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)                   <--- Note 3
      max: 255 (1)                  <--- Note 3
      mean: 50.3212 (0.197338)
      standard deviation: 101.351 (0.397456)
      kurtosis: 0.316613
      skewness: 1.52096
      entropy: 0.0954769
    ...
    ...
```

I have annotated with arrows and notes on the right above.

Note 1: This tells me the image is greyscale + alpha

Note 2: This tells me all the greyscale pixels are black, since the max is zero and the min is zero

Note 3: This tells me that there are some fully transparent pixels, and some fully opaque pixels

Comment: Thanks so much!! I want to ask how to get these meta info with opencv3? I only get width, height, size, and dtype.

Comment: I am not sure which meta info you mean. If you mean the info I gave in the first two paragraphs of my answer, I will add an explanation to my answer in a moment. If you mean something else, please say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Paint is transforming the images somehow making their format incompatible with the 'typical' imread routine. I'm not sure what's happening, it might be related to paint already removing the alpha channel which OpenCV also wants to remove (according to their docs, didn't take a look at the code). Luckily you can circumvent it:

```
I_not_ok = cv2.imread(ImagePath, CV2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

I_ok = I_not_ok[:,:,3]

cv2.namedWindow('Image_ok', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Image_ok', I_ok)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It works!! I add: image = 255 - image, to get the white-background one. Glad to see your answer! Thanks!